# Were the societies envisioned in the Dharmasastras ever reflective of reality?

Tags: india, social-history, hinduism

Were the [Dharmasastras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharma%C5%9B%C4%81stra#:%7E:text=Dharma%C5%9B%C4%81stra%20(Sanskrit%3A%20%E0%A4%A7%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0)%20is,and%20conflicting%20points%20of%20view.) like [Manusmriti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manusmriti) and [Yajnavalkya Smriti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y%C4%81j%C3%B1avalkya_Sm%E1%B9%9Bti) ever implemented in ancient Indian society ? Or did they only represent the ideal or utopia Hinduism imagines could be achieved?

Comment: I am looking also for scriptural evidence. If there are any

Comment: What do you think of the answer then? It doesn't quote scriptures. @bhatnagarprakhar

Comment: Welcome @bhatnagarPrakhar - I think this is a good question and welcome here, but I'd recommend that you do two things. First, document any preliminary research you've done (like most science sites, it is normal to document prior research), second, you may wish to provide links to assist those who are less familiar with Hindu practice.  I've edited in a few I've found, but _please_ correct me if I'm wrong, or if there are more appropriate links.

Answer (score 5):

Yes as per Historians Dharma Sastras were never implemented.

> In the opinion of the best contemporary orientalists, it [Manusmriti]
> does not, as a whole, represent a set of rules ever actually
> administered in Hindustan. It is in great part an ideal picture of
> that which, in the view of a Brahmin, ought to be law [Page 204,
> Family Law and Customary Law in Asia by David Buxbaum [1](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-94-017-6216-8) ]
>
> There is
> no historical evidence for either an active propagation or
> implementation of Dharmasastra by a ruler or any state –
> as distinct from other forms of recognizing, respecting and using the
> text. Thinking of Dharmasastra as a legal code and of its authors as
> lawgivers is thus a serious misunderstanding of its history[ [2](https://archive.org/details/spiritofhindulawoup_202003_498_w/page/n27/mode/2up) ]

Comment: *"in the view of a Brahmin"* - lol, Manu was Kshatriya.